# What is behind media queries ? Why media queries (with width) are better than Javascript resize event?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, media-queries, window-resize

I've read a post saying Javascript event 'resize' fires every pixel and that media queries with width were better, but I didn't find anything about what is behind media queries. And I don't see how it could be possible than there is no every pixels action with media query, even the browser needs to be aware of his change of size every pixels. So why media query should be better than Javascript resize event (at least for a change in width)?

PS : Sorry if there is any mistake in my English, it is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the javascript resize event you have to focus on a lot of things such as: clientWidth, clientHeight, innerWidth, innerHeight, outerWidth, outerHeight, offsetWidth and/or offsetHeight properties.

And for media queries, it applies when the certain condition is true, not only this, it has many more benefits which you can find over here.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Also they are totally different, resize is a DOM event occurred when the viewport was resized. In Media Queries there are much more properties, than those connected to the viewport size. You can control the layout by the media, import style rules etc.

**CSS load faster than Javascript.. javascript will work when the html is rendered.. if you load javascript before the html or the particular html tag is rendered it will not work. Thus media query is better option. P.S its time to change your senior way of using resize function.. :)**

### Edited

I can think of three important concerns here:

**JavaScript support** - onresize wouldn't fire at all if client disables JS in his browser. Nowadays it is almost impossible to surf the web with disabled JS, but still a valid concern.

**Animations** - if you plan to animate transition from one window size to the other, then CSS animations are the way to go, especially on mobile devices. CSS animations use hardware acceleration when available and thus are very fast and efficient, consuming less CPU and run more smoothly.
You could still use onresize to trigger CSS animations from JS (add a class, change an animated CSS property), but consider 3.

**DOM traversal** - either your JS code, either browser internally, in order to manipulate DOM one has to travers it.
CSS properties are applied to DOM elements by traversing the DOM and matching elements according to CSS selectors. This process is constantly optimized by browser vendors and made as efficient as possible. Of course it also depends on how you write your CSS, but browser optimizes you selectors internaly once and apply them many times.
On the other hand JS also has to traverse DOM in order to do any manipulation. But with JS it is up to you how efficient is your DOM traversal (document.all, document.getElementById, document.querySelector etc).
I would use media queries whenever possible and CSS animations triggered either by media query rule, either by other JS event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just don't know if we resize the window from 650px to 750px, and there is a media query changing something at min-width: 700px, the media query will still ask the size of the viewport every pixel right ? And if I am not wrong it won't be better in term of performance than a resize.event. I am just trying to understand how media queries work and why it can be better to use them instead of javascript events.

Comment: [I've edited my answer again, please check.] and I understand Forejy, but if you see the last paragraph (text in bold) you will get your answer. Both of them are equally good, both of them focus on every pixel change. Media Queries are faster than JavaScript and are slightly more responsive.

Comment: If you're satisfied with my answer then please accept it by clicking on the checkbox.